# gulp command not found (Mac OS)

Tags: node.js, gulp

I have been trying to setup an angular js project with yo, grunt and generator-gulp-angular. Although I install all packages, gulp comand is not found, however it works if I go inside node_modules.

This code will explain my issue:

```
$ npm -v
# 2.5.1
$ npm install -g yo
$ npm install -g generator-gulp-angular
$ mkdir client && cd $_
$ yo gulp-angular ng_demo
$ gulp serve
# command not found
$ node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js serve
# works
```

I am using zsh. What may be going wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check that you installed gulp globally:

```
npm install -g gulp
```

Another idea is to add `scripts` to your package.json file along the lines of:

```
{
  "name": "testing-app",
  "version": "0.9",
  "scripts": {
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "serve": "gulp serve"
  }
}
```

Then use `npm run serve`...

Comment: Do we always need to use sudo to install gulp globally ? I get red errors if using user so had to use sudo - then when I exit to user and try to run gulp I get command not found. grrrr

Comment: This worked for me except I had to add 'sudo' in front of it and then type in my password.